# Azure Runbook Failure with Connect-AzAccount -Identity

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity

I have been working to convert our runbooks in Azure to use Managed Identity and keep running into an error when running these commands from Azure. They run fine directly on the machines with the Hybrid Workers and if the Runbook is run directly on the hybrid worker but in many cases the runbooks start on Azure itself.

Section of code:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
Add-AzAccount -Identity
```

Error Message Example:
Add-AzAccount : An error occurred while sending the request...[Connect-AzAccount], HttpRequestException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand

Searching thru I wasn't able to find a solution only similar problems, I have also updated these module so the current Modules loaded are:
AZAccounts 1.9.1
AZResources 2.3.0

Comment: I dont think it should work on Azure, you cant assign Managed Identity to a runbook, right?

Comment: Yeah you can't add it directly to a runbook. I was hoping to replace the code that has to bring in the certificate by using managed identity but maybe it's not possible?$servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName

            Add-AzAccount `
                -ServicePrincipal `
                -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
                -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
                -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint

Comment: yeah, you can do that, why not?

Comment: I think I might need to have two versions of the code one for running on Azure and one on the Hybrid workers, it seems to work when replacing that section of code but only when running on the hybrid worker. Thank you for helping work that out in my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just have an if condition (based on some arbitrary check) and if it fails - run the managed identity login, otherwize certificate login, that way you dont have to have 2 version on the same script